# Integrate sharethis in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, script-tag, sharethis

I need to integrate sharethis in my reactjs application. I need that script to execute only in one component. Currently this is how I have implemented.

```
 componentWillMount() {
 const script = document.createElement("script");
 script.src ="//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=242434664&product=sop?r=" +new Date().getTime();
 script.async = true;
 script.id = "shareThisId";
 document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

The problem with this is since this component is mounted through react routing and  page reload doesn't happen, the script doesn't re-execute.

I tried removing the script tag on componentWillUnmount lifecycle by using removeChild, but that still doesn't re-execute the script on mounting and I learnt that it happens because of this - **The removed child node still exists in memory** according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild.

Also, the script needs to re-execute on mount so that I get updated share count each time.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is with the official plugin, but it still doesn't work... consider this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52770761/1669091

Answer (score 4):

I work at sharethis, and we recently publish a reactjs plugin at https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharethis-reactjs. You can try to install and use it more conveniently.

Let me know if you have any issue while using it, and I'm happy to help.

Comment: getting this issue `Module not found: Can't resolve 'aws-sdk`

Comment: Hi Rubel, we didn't include the `aws-sdk` in the library dependencies, and in fact we didn't use any external libraries. Can you double check if the module is included in your project independently from our plugin?

Comment: https://github.com/sharethis-github/sharethis-reactjs/issues/3 here is the issue we are facing

Comment: Hi Rubel, we solved the issue and you can try to use the latest version now.

Comment: I'm not sure what the issue is, but it still doesn't work... consider this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52770761/1669091

Answer (score 1):

Hao Xu,
For what it's worth, I got tired of trying to make the "official" sharethis-reactjs package work...

You'll need to include the js in index.html

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//platform-api.sharethis.com/js/sharethis.js#property=YOUR-PROPPERTY-KEY&product=inline-share-buttons' async='async'></script>
```

So this is what I wrote... you'll want to configure it your way of course

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {isMobile} from 'react-device-detect';


export class ShareButtons extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        var defaultNetworks = isMobile  ? ['facebook', 'twitter', 'pinterest', 'googleplus', 'sharethis', 'sms', 'email'] 
                                        : ['facebook', 'twitter', 'pinterest', 'googleplus', 'sharethis',  'email'];

    this.state = {
        config: {
            id: this.props.id || 'sharethis-inline-buttons',
            networks: this.props.networks || defaultNetworks,
            alignment: this.props.alignment || "right",
            enabled: this.props.enabled !== 'false' || true,
            font_size: this.props.font_size || 11,
            padding: this.props.padding || 8,
            radius: this.props.radius || 20,
            networks: this.props.networks || defaultNetworks,
            size: this.props.size || 32,
            show_mobile_buttons: this.props.show_mobile_buttons !== 'false' || true,
            spacing: this.props.spacing || 2,
            url: this.props.url || window.location.href,
            title: this.props.title || document.title,
            image: this.props.image || "https://18955-presscdn-pagely.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ShareThisLogo2x.png", // useful for pinterest sharing buttons
            description: this.props.description || document.getElementsByTagName('meta')["description"].content,
            username: this.props.username || "ChadSteele" // custom @username for twitter sharing
        }
    };



    }

    componentDidMount(){
        window.__sharethis__.load('inline-share-buttons', this.state.config);
    }

    render(){
        return <span id={this.state.config.id || 'sharethis-inline-buttons'}></span>
    }
}

export default ShareButtons;
```